# Why does Logic X always make my tracks HUGE when I press A to edit automation?

Tags: logic-pro, automation

Driving me bonkers. I have to option-scroll to ensmallen my tracks every time I press A.

I've seen some similar questions elsewhere but no working solution. Is this a setting or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea of having the tracks expand when editing automation is that it gives you more room to make the changes, which allows for more precision.  I've liked this feature, so I haven't looked for a way to change it but I would recommend looking in the settings for automation section of the preferences menu.  So I can say definitively that this is not a bug, however, since I don't know if there is a way to change it or not, I'm not sure if we would just call this a feature or also a setting.

The reason I like this feature is that it truly does give me more precision.  Depending on what sort of changes you are making, this can be very important.  For instance, when I am automating volume, I want to be able to get very specific values, as plus or minus a few db can make a very large difference in your overall mix.  I'm still on Logic 9, so I'm not sure if this works but there is another function to be able to make even more precise changes as well.  If you hold the ctrl key while clicking and dragging the automation point, it should move in 0.1 db increments, instead of skipping around by larger increments based on how far you are zoomed in.

Overall, I wouldn't think that having to zoom out with option+scroll is much of an issue, as it is pretty quick, but I can understand it interrupting your workflow.  One suggestion I would have is to try out the "screensets" functionality.  This allows you to have a bunch of different screens set up at once that can be viewed separately.  We start off any project with one screenset but if you were to press any of the number keys, except zero, it will open up another screenset.  In any additional screensets you can zoom in/out, access specific tracks or views, open automation, etc., and it will remember where you are and what you had open.  So I might suggest creating another screenset by pressing 2 (or whatever number you prefer), then setting up your automation view as you like it.  Once this is configured, you can press 1 to get back to the first screenset, where you could continue to arrange, record, etc., then whenever you need to make automation adjustments, just press 2 to pull up the second screenset, which will still have the automation view enabled as well as the zooming in/out that you had done previously.  You would still have to do this for every new project but you should only have to do it once.  I'm pretty sure that after you save and close the project, the screensets that you set up should all still be configured as they were when you last saved, but I'm not completely certain of that.

Answer (score 0):

just press Control Z (Toggle Zoom Focused Track)